# how to disable future and past dates  in calendar popup using zend with php

Tags: php, zend-framework

For date of birth field i want the users to select past dates 15 years back from present date and disable all the other

Comment: Read this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.date.datesandtimes.html

Answer (score 1):

Calendar controllers in user end work using Javascript since it needs to be user friendly. So you have to control that from the calendar popup. There are plenty of javascript plugins available for this. o disable past and future dates you have to use options given in relevant plugin.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

http://javascriptcalendar.org/

However if you need to do a server validation for this you can use following source.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.basic.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use this class from my PHP-Pike library: https://github.com/php-pike/Pike/blob/master/Validate/DateRange.php

If you using it on a form element:

```
<?php
$form = new Zend_Form();
$element = Zend_Form_Element_Text('birthdate');
$element->setLabel('Some label');
$element->addValidator(new Pike_Validate_DateRange(array('lt' => Zend_Date::now()->subYear(15)));
$form->addElement($element);
?>
```

This is server-side validation. You can use Prasad his answer to do client-side validation. It's wise to do both.

If you use the Jquery-ui datepicker it's nice to use the Jquery maskedinput plugin as well to strict the user to fill in a date himself in a certain format. Something like:

```
$('your-date-field').mask('9999-99-99', {
    completed : function() {
        $('your-date-field').datepicker('hide');
    }
});
```

Which will increase usabillity a lot :)

Comment: The code for Pike's date range validator no longer seems to be available. Has it moved? Was it dropped?

Comment: No, the URL changed, you could look at the 1.4 branch: https://github.com/php-pike/pike/tree/1.4.x